# Is it ever correct to use "on" after "continue"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is it ever grammatically correct to use the word *"on"* after the word *"continue"*?

as in:

> "After this break, we will continue on with the broadcast."

Comment: Yes, it is sometimes correct.  The line you quote seems syntactically valid and reasonably idiomatic.

Comment: You could just say “continue the broadcast”, and there’s a case to be made for stripping out unnecessary verbal scaffolding. But in spoken English, with no explicit punctuation, adding in redundant connecting words often makes sentences clearer.

Comment: If the question is whether the words "continue" and "on" can ever appear next to each other in a syntactically sound sentence in which the "on" is not redundant, the answer is yes. For example: "Let us continue on our way." But what distinguishes that example from "We will continue on with the broadcast" is that in the first  example "on" functions as a preposition, whereas in the second one "on" functions as part of a verb phrase("continue on")  that conveys essentially the same information as "continue" by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Though, to many, it is idiomatically redundant, it is **not incorrect**.

Here is a corroborating source:
https://www.dailywritingtips.com/continue-and-continue-on/

Comment: You mean it's redundant to continue on and on and on about something?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly OK.  There are many other examples of this kind of construction (see below).  The word "on" is an adverbial particle and in this case and others remains fixed; it cannot move.  For example it wouldn't be OK to say "After this break we will continue with the broadcast *on*."  In many cases, the particle can move, as in "Please, take off your shoes," or "Please, take your shoes off."

Here are two examples similar to yours:

I hope she moves *on* with her life
We need to continue *on* with the mission.
After he caught his breath, he continued *on* with the race.

Your question asks about "continue" and whether or not it can be paired with "on."  This is a matter of taste and a person's ideas about the verb continue.  In my opinion "on" can be.  [This](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/continue+on+with.html) page had numerous examples which seemed fine to me.  Can you leave out "on?"  Sure.  Adverbial particles give extra information about the verb.  For example "up" indicates a completion of something: "finish up," "zip up," mess up," and "pack up."  "On" as a particle indicates many things.  In your example, it indicates the furtherance of an activity and helps the verb "continue" which [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/continue) to keep doing something.

If you'd like to learn more, [this](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/grammar-review-1-particles-and-phrasal-verbs/) is an article to explore.

Comment: Just a quibble about continuing "with the broadcast *on*" - it's fine if what's being continued isn't the broadcast. You could continue a painting lesson with the broadcast on or off, for example.

Comment: @Lawrence  Yes, but the words "on" or "off" in your example have a different function...they're not adverbial particles, but adjective adjuncts.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect/superfluous usage.  "After this break, we will continue on with the broadcast."  "After this break, we will continue with the broadcast."  "Continue" meaning "proceed."  Otherwise, the question would be "on" what?